# Is it ok to let Mac air run 24 full hours?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Air (11-inch, 2011) ,I am now downloading iTuneU courses 24 hours.There is only one app iTunes running,is it ok?

Comment: I haven't turned off my iMac for a month, and my MacBook Pro for a week. A PC which work as a server in my room haven't been turned off for like 3 months or so. You'll be fine!

Comment: We have a small cubicle for undergrad students where they can work on their internship projects, and those Macs haven't been shut down for a year or so. We would notice if they would try to restart them since we would have to log in with a password.

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course. I had my MacBook running for a week once. And as long as you don't do any heavy tasks, such as rendering or video compression, you won't have any overheating issues.

Comment: You won't have heat issues regardless on any machine provided it is in full working condition. That's what fans are for and they aren't designed with some minimal uptime in mind. Any PC is designed to crunch instructions for as long as you wish without fault.

Comment: And since the MacBook Air has an SSD, there should be even less heat development than in the regular MacBook (Pro). I noticed once, that the left side, where the Hard Disk is located, got a little bit warm (but not hot), when I let Disk Utility do a thorough secure erase for a couple of days (1 TB disk).

Answer (score 1):

One more thing I really want to mention. I would not recommend to use any of those MacBook body cases, such as this one for example [image]

Basically, the cooling of the MacBooks works through a gap below the screen where the hinges are, the aluminum body, and the keyboard. If you cover you MacBook in plastic, it will reduce the heat escape through the body. Also, I often see people with key board covers. I think this is a really stupid idea, because it prevents air circulation in the MacBook and causes the heat bottling up inside.

However, I have to say that at home, even if I have my MacBook closed and connected to a external monitor, I never had any issues when it ran for a couple of days.

Also, what I noticed when I did heavy stuff on my MacBook, is that the vans will produce some extra noise that. You can take this as a warning signal. However, the MacBook would also turn off itself automatically, if it gets too hot, to protect itself from heat damage.

To keep it short: I wouldn't worry about letting your MacBook running for a week or so to just download stuff, that's just fine.

Comment: Thanks！I am just thinking about getting a body case like this.

Comment: actually, i use both of the case and the keyboard protector, after a month of using them, i took of the protector and it looked so dirty/dusty, also during this month i could pick food/dust from this protector before it cases in damages under the keys; Also the protector is very helpful, it prevented a lot of scratches, and there are those fan-friendly cases such as TopCase. that has several holes in different places to keep it good

Comment: It really depends on the usage, but I never had any dirt on or in my MacBook. All I do is to put it into a well-padded sleeve (Case Logic, $13 on Amazon) before I put it into my backpack.

Answer (score -1):

Had a friend rarely switch off his devices when everything turns to Apple, even his Air. Shall be ok to keep it running for couples of hours.

Answer (score -1):

I have several Macs and they are only shut down when there will be no humans using them for **2** or more days.

The only moving parts are the Hard Drives and they are engineered to run for years as sealed units.

Of course, we either put our Macs to sleep or hibernation.

Comment: The Airs do not contain any moving parts aside from the fans. Their hard drives are solid state.

Comment: Also Macs are meant to be to put to sleep. Aside installing updates, entering an airplane, or performing hardware upgrades, there is no reason to restart or shutdown a Mac.